# Java Mail SMTP: Removing internal host names and IP addresses from mail message headers

Tags: java, security, smtp, jakarta-mail

Mail message header is exposing information about hostname and internal IP address(first hop Server). Attacker can easily get information about internal server IP and it is a serious treat.

```
Message-ID: <5f698024.1c69fb81.621c8.e573SMTPIN_ADDED_BROKEN@mx.google.com>
X-Google-Original-Message-ID: <1634982533.0.1600749603315.JavaMail.production.domain.com>
Received: from <hostname> (unknown [10.11.XXX.XXX]) by devmail01.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 93DF9C0BD3 for <username.r@gmail.com>; Mon, 21 Sep 2020 21:40:02 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 10:05:42 +0530 (IST)
From: mailer <mailer@us.abcd-mail.com>
To: username.r@gmail.com
Subject: [502FE0F6] org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException report for http://localhost:8080
```

So I added `props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", "production.domain.com");` to SMTP configuration and now I see hostname is coming as "production.domain.com"
But still Internal IP is exposed and which is being used for reverse DNS lookup

```
Received: from production.domain.com (unknown [10.11.XXX.XXX]) by devmail01.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 2B933C0016 for <username.r@gmail.com>; Mon, 21 Sep 2020 23:57:04 -0700 (PDT)
```

How do I remove internal IP address for message headers?
Is it possible to prevent reverse DNS lookup?

Comment: The IP address you posted is a public address, not an internal IP, FYI

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I agree with you. I have not posted actual internal IP in the question

Comment: Isn't [Received header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4021#page-17) controlled by the MTA and not JavaMail?  The changes would have to be made to the MTA and not JavaMail.

Comment: @NaghaveerR did you solve this issue? I am experiencing the same problem.